# Should I drop a btree index on a column after adding a unique constraint?

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint

On one of my existing tables I have a btree index. I am now adding a unique constraint to this column. I know behind the scenes it will add a UNIQUE btree index to this column as well.

In this scenario, should I drop the original btree index added to the column to prevent redundant indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the unique constraint is defined on the same columns as the index, and the columns are in the same order, the index is redundant with the index created by the constraint and can be dropped without any problems.